# Help needed to write a LINQ with GROUP bY(C#3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a datatable whose structure is as under

```
Week    Dates       Key_Factors Factor_Values
--- -----       ----------- -------------
1   29/12/2000  Factor_1    19.20
1   29/12/2000  Factor_2    20.67
1   29/12/2000  Factor_3    10
2   21/12/2007  Factor_1    20.54
2   21/12/2007  Factor_4    21.70
```

I have a Object model like

```
WeekNumber(int)
Dates(Datetime)
FactorDictionary (Dictionary<string,double>)
```

I am trying to populate the data from DataTable to my Object Model  whose needed output is as under

```
Desired Output
----------------
WeekNumber : 1
Dates   : 29/12/2000
FactorDictionary: 
    Key_Factors: Factor_1   Factor_Values:19.20
    Key_Factors: Factor_2   Factor_Values:20.67
    Key_Factors: Factor_3   Factor_Values:10

WeekNumber : 2
Dates   : 21/12/2007
FactorDictionary: 
    Key_Factors: Factor_1   Factor_Values:20.54
    Key_Factors: Factor_4   Factor_Values:21.70
```

i.e. The result is grouped by weeks.

Can I achieve the same by using LINQ.

I am using C#(3.0) with framework(3.5)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit confused by the way you have worded the question, but yes, you can easily group by weeks from a DateTime field using LINQ.  The following group by examples [should get you started.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx#simple1)